# Measure how many times iOS can draw per frame

Tags: javascript, ios, performance, benchmarking, graphic

I am trying to benchmark how many times iOS natively can draw between frame refresh compared to HTML5/JavaScript.

Using this JavaScript I get a number for how may times the browser can draw during the 33 ms (30 Hz):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = document.getElementById('img');

var draw = function(load) {
    var angle = 0.01;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(200,200);
    for (var i=0; i<load; i++) {
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    ctx.restore();
};

var t, previousTime;
var drawLoad = 1;
var slowCount = 0;
var maxSlow = 10;

var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

t = previousTime = Date.now();

var tick = function() {
    var maximumFrameTime = 1000/30; // 30 FPS
    t = Date.now();
    var elapsed = t - previousTime;
    previousTime = t;
    if (elapsed < maximumFrameTime || slowCount < maxSlow) {
        if (elapsed < maximumFrameTime) {
            drawLoad+=10;
        } else {
            slowCount++;
        }
        draw(drawLoad);
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    } else {
      // found maximum sustainable load at 30 FPS
      document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = ("could draw "+(drawLoad)+" in " + maximumFrameTime + " ms");
    }
};
requestAnimationFrame(tick);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tbhZs/117/ for complete code with HTML-markup.

I have fiddled around in objective-c without finding a fair way to get a comparable number. Is there a way to produce a comparable benchmark natively in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Try instruments tool. you can measure the frames per socond via the core animation instrument.

Comment: But it is not the FPS I am trying to capture. It is how many times iOS can draw between screen updates.